# Web clock with copy button (and accurate server-based time)

Tags: gratis, web-apps, timezones

I often need to copy the exact time that I do something, so that I can find the results in the logs. I also often need to tell customers to do that, for a given timezone which might not be theirs. So I am looking for:

- A website that shows the time
- There MUST be a very visible button to copy the time (for copy/paste)
- The timezone must be set in the URL, for instance clock.com/PST
- Gratis for the visitor
- Time must not be browser-based. It must be retrieved from the server, so that the time is correct even if the visitor's computer clock has some delay.